# vertical position of an a-element and button-element

Tags: html, css, position

I want to style a `<button>` and `<a>` element both into the same format. I use the following code:

```css
button,
a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#dummy-block {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dummy-block"></div>
<button>My Button</button>
<a>My Link</a>
```

But the `<button>` element seems to ignore the height and my `<a>` element does not touch the edge of the black dummy `<div>` above:

[image]

You can test the code in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyrrcrqc/1/

Comment: You can use `float:left` Instead of`display: inline-block;`

Comment: @Maddy: Thank you for your answer. But I do not want to add a clearfix after all my button lines.

Comment: Try to give margin 0 for a to make it touch the dummy div.. 
Try removing the padding from the button to make the height work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
button, a {
    background-color: white;
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000 inset;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Or:-

```
button, a {
    background-color: white;
    border: medium none;
    vertical-align:top;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
```

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyoqcqx/4/)**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyoqcqx/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The button does now touch the edge of the div above. But if you look precisely, you can see, that the a element is higher than the button element. You solved only a part of my problem.

Comment: This problem because of border, `button` take the border inside and `a` take outside. try the update answer may it will helps you

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the default box-sizing method for button is `border-box` while that for inline-block is `content-box`. So:

- 35px height means the `<a>` is actually 37px tall (border ***adds*** 2px)
- 35px height means the `<button>` tag is 35px tall (35px ***includes*** the border)

Set the `box-sizing: border-box` on both elements.

```css
button,
a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#dummy-block {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dummy-block"></div>
<button>My Button</button>
<a>My Link</a>
```

Comment: You still need `vertical-align: top` in `button, a`to solve the asker's initial question (ensure the border of the anchor element touches the `#dummy-block` element)

Answer (score 2):

try adding `vertical-align: bottom` to `button, a` selector

```css
button, a
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#dummy-block
{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dummy-block"></div>

<button>Okay</button>
<a>Edit</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also in your example the a element has not the same height than the button element.

Comment: @Simon you have write Different height for 'button' and 'a' because button has default value

Answer (score 1):

```
    a
    {
        padding:1px 15px;
    }
    button,a
    {
        border: solid 1px black;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        font-family: 'Arial';

        font-size: 13px;
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        display: inline-block;

    }
    button
    {
        padding: 0 15px;    
    }
```